# Sending an email on squirrelmail

Tags: ubuntu, putty

I created two users from ubuntu and tried to send mail on my squirrelmail.

However, for some reason when I logged into one of my accounts and tried to send an email on squirrelmail the other user that I created is somehow not getting it.

Comment: Hello 1. You're going to need to provide more detail in your question to be able to get any (useful) answers. How have you configured SquirrelMail to send email? Do the log files show that the message was sent? If not, what do they show? Is the message in the user's mailbox? How have you configured the app to receive email?